# Can you use var() in :root pseudo-class CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a website for an organization, but for one of the forms, the background image was interfering with the * color for the required inputs. I used `:root` in my CSS so I could add variables. For some reason, the `calc` function looked like it was not working because the new variable `--special` was still at its base color `rgb(250, 128, 114)`. The `calc` function's right side was the variable `--down`, which was set to a number so the `rgb` function would still work. I was accessing the `--down` variable using `var()` , but like I said, the `calc` function was returning the same value, not the new subtracted value. I'm not sure if you can actually access defined variables using `var()` when you are in the `:root` pseudo-class. I am also not interested in switching to a new text color because it might not match the theme.

```css
span.required {
  color: salmon;
}

:root {
  --down: 15;
  --special: rgb(calc(250 - var(--down)), calc(128 - var(--down)), calc(114 - var(--down)));
}

span.required.special3 {
  color: var(--special) !important;
}
```

```html
<label for='fname'>...</label>
<input type='text' name='fname' required placeholder='...' />
<br /> This is supposed to be the new color
<span class='required special3'>*</span>
<br />
<br />
<label for='interested'>...</label>
<select name='interested' required>
  <option value='y'>Yes</option>
  <option value='n'>No</option>
  <option value='m'>Maybe</option>
  <option value='o'>Other</option>
</select>
<br /> This is the regular color.
<span class='required'>*</span>
```

Comment: your code works fine

Comment: Could you describe more why you think the color has not changed? Looking at the two asterisks it is clear that the calculated one is darker. At least on my test on IOS Safari. What browser and OS are you on?

Comment: I use Chrome as my web browser and my OS is MacOS Monterey.

Comment: The color does not look changed because it still does not contrast the background image. I want the darker asterisk to look more darker than the others, but on my view, the color is not changed.